# Scala macro: Function in scala annotation

Tags: scala, annotations, macros

I am implementing a Scala macro taking **a function** within an annotation. I am able to generate proper code but the compilation fails without any meaningful error.

## Example:

Let us have a macro providing a name of the given class. The macro can optionally read the transformation function `(String => String)` over the class.

### Macro:

```
package foo

import scala.language.experimental.macros
import scala.reflect.macros.blackbox
import scala.annotation.StaticAnnotation

class transform( value: String => String ) extends StaticAnnotation

object Macro {

  def name[ T: c.WeakTypeTag ]( c: blackbox.Context ): c.Tree = {
    import c.universe._
    // type of the class
    val tag = implicitly[ WeakTypeTag[ T ] ]
    // class name
    val name = tag.tpe.typeSymbol.name.toString
    // Option[ Annotation ], if there is a @transform
    val annotation = tag.tpe.typeSymbol.annotations.find( _.tree.tpe <:< weakTypeOf[ transform ] )
    // Option[ Tree ] with the transformation function
    val transformation = annotation.map( _.tree.children.tail.head )
    // String, either class name or the transformed name
    transformation.map( f => q"$f apply $name" ).getOrElse( q"$name" )
  }
}
```

### Uncompilable Test:

```
package foo

import scala.language.experimental.macros

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

@transform( _.toUpperCase )
case class Baz( foo: String, bar: String )

object Baz {
  def name: String = macro Macro.name[ Baz ]
}

object MacroSpecs extends Specification {

  "macro should provide a class name" in {
    Baz.name mustEqual "BAZ"
  }
}
```

Compilation error:

```
[error] (test:compileIncremental) java.util.NoSuchElementException: key not found: package foo
```

### Note and Working Test:

I figured out that when I move the `Baz` class into `MacroSpecs` object, the compilation passes and everything works.

```
package foo

import scala.language.experimental.macros

import org.specs2.mutable.Specification

object MacroSpecs extends Specification {

  @transform( _.toUpperCase )
  case class Baz( foo: String, bar: String )

  object Baz {
    def name: String = macro Macro.name[ Baz ]
  }

  "macro should provide a class name" in {
    Baz.name mustEqual "BAZ"
  }
}
```

### Questions:

1. What is the difference between these two tests?
2. Why the first test does not compile while the other does?
3. How to make the first test working?